# Pass POCO around in a Asp.Net MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having an Asp.Net MVC 3 app where i need to pass around a Viewmodel to different Views and i am wondering what is the correct approach to accomplish this.
Once the user logs in and gets the user object,i need to use the same user object to Views such as ViewUser, EditUser etc.I am currently passing the User id(Once the user logs in succesfully) in @html.actionlink method as objectroutes and getting the user object from the database every time.

Is this the right approach ? I didnt want to use Session.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you want to use Session?  It's designed for this very scenario... to cache data that will be needed for the duration that a user is logged in.

When a view alters the User object (EditUser), just update the Session at the same time you update the database.

Comment: Thanks.I have seen many Stackoverflow articles where they suggest to save the Id somewhere and retrieve the object every time from the database, when navigating to any other view. Is it a good idea to save the entire object in the Session ? I was planning to use FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(id, false) and use the id in other views to retrieve he object.